# Función Bloquea GUI en tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Mi problema es el siguiente:

Tengo una ventana muy simple de tkinter, en la cual he puesto un solo boton. Cuando el usuario presiona dicho boton se ejecuta una funcion. Esta funcion busca algunos archivos segun el noombre y si no existe muestra un mensaje. El proceso demora algunos minutos, pero mientras tanto la interfaz grafica se bloquea con el famoso (no responde).
Lo que necesito es que mientras se ejecuta esta proceso, el usuario pueda seguir utilizando la GUI sin problema. Sospecho que la solucion esta relacionada con hilos pero no estoy seguro de como se hace.
Aqui el codigo:

```
from tkinter import *
import os.path
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import time
def verificacion():
    messagebox.showinfo("Exito", "Todos los archivos existen!!")


def mensajeOmitidos(archivos):
    messagebox.showinfo("Omitido", archivos)


archivos = ["archivo1.py", "archivo2.py", "archivo3.py"]
# Esta es la funcion llamada con el boton
# En este ejemplo no demora mucho, pero el mio
# necesita conectarse a una base de datos por lo que le toma mas tiempo


def funcionConsulta():
    time.sleep(3)
    cont = ""
    for x in archivos:
        if not os.path.isfile(x):
            cont = cont + "," + x
    if len(cont) != 0:
        mensajeOmitidos(cont)
    else:
        verificacion()


raiz = Tk()
raiz.geometry("500x500")
raiz.resizable(width=False, height=False)
botonConsulta = tk.Button(raiz, text="actualizar", command=funcionConsulta)
botonConsulta.grid(row=5, column=5)
raiz.mainloop()
```

Les dejo un pantallazo de mi programa de prueba, en este punto llevaba como 3 minutos asi.
[image: pantallazo de la aplicacion bloquea]

Debo aclarar que el codigo de prueba no demora tanto como el original, ya que en este ultimo debo conectarme a una base de datos y hacer muchas mas cosas.

Agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan dar, estoy pendiente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
from tkinter import *
import os.path
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import time
from threading import Thread

def verificacion():
    messagebox.showinfo("Exito", "Todos los archivos existen!!")



def mensajeOmitidos(archivos):
    messagebox.showinfo("Omitido", archivos)



archivos = ["archivo1.py", "archivo2.py", "archivo3.py"]
# Esta es la funcion llamada con el boton
# En este ejemplo no demora mucho, pero el mio
# necesita conectarse a una base de datos por lo que le toma mas tiempo


def funcionConsulta():
    time.sleep(3)
    cont = ""
    for x in archivos:
        if not os.path.isfile(x):
            cont = cont + "," + x
    if len(cont) != 0:
        mensajeOmitidos(cont)
    else:
        verificacion()

def button():
    Thread(target=funcionConsulta).start()

raiz = Tk()
raiz.geometry("500x500")
raiz.resizable(width=False, height=False)
botonConsulta = tk.Button(raiz, text="actualizar", command=button)
botonConsulta.grid(row=5, column=5)
raiz.mainloop()
```

Comment: Muchas gracias amigo eres todo un crack. Me salvaste la vida, era justo lo que necesitaba.